# Why is the desktop not showing when typing dir on cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe, desktop

i can not acess Desktop by "cd Desktop".

Ps: I had onedrive linked to my microsoft account, I disabled it and the problem persists (I don't know if that influences something)

[image: Image Embed]

Comment: While you might have disabled OneDrive from syncing your changes to your Desktop folder, it's still more then likely, within the OneDrive directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Desktop folder does not need to live inside your User Profile directory. See if it has been moved or redirected by inspecting Desktop Properties and clicking on the Location tab:

[image: Desktop Location Tab]